# Problems on the computation of cohomology ring of torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the following simplicial complex decomposition of the torus.

[image]

On the image, we have a ordering of the vertices. The $1$'s on the $1$-simplices are related to $f$ and $g$, which are  (?) $1$-cochains on this simplicial decomposition: $f$ evaluates as $1$ on the $1$-simplices which a imaginary horizontal line cuts, and $g$ evaluates as $1$ on the $1$-simplices which a imaginary vertical line cuts (this is what the diagram is intended to show).

Now, this diagram is on Bredon (topology and geometry), and he asserts that $g$ is a co-chain. However... $\delta g(\langle 2,3,8\rangle)=g(\langle 3,8\rangle -\langle 2,8 \rangle + \langle 2,3 \rangle)=1-0+1=2 \neq 0$ (we are taking coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$). Am I missing something?

Furthermore, he says that $f \cup g(\langle 5,8,9 \rangle)=1,$ however $f \cup g(\langle 5, 8,9\rangle)=(-1)^{1\cdot 1}f(\langle 5,8\rangle)g(\langle 8, 9 \rangle)=-1.$ Again, did I miss something?